# not able to figure out what is wrong with my nodemcu code

Tags: nodemcu

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <FirebaseArduino.h>

//Firebase settings
#define FIREBASE_HOST "..........firebaseio.com/"     //cant share
#define FIREBASE_AUTH "..............."               //cant share   

//Wi-Fi settings
#define WIFI_SSID "kello"
#define WIFI_PASSWORD "8888"

//Define trigger and echo digital pins
const int trigPin = 4;
const int echoPin = 3;

// The amount of time the ultrassonic wave will be travelling for
long duration = 0;
// Define the distance variable
double distance = 0;

void setup()
{
     Serial.begin(9600);
    // Connect to Wi-Fi
    Serial.print("Wi-Fi...");
    WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASSWORD);
    Serial.print("Connecting...");
    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
    {
        Serial.print(".");
        delay(500);
    }
    Serial.println();
    Serial.print("Connected to: ");
    Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

    Firebase.begin(FIREBASE_HOST, FIREBASE_AUTH);

    // Ultrasonic sensor, set echo as Input and trigger as Output
    pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);


}

void loop()
{

    getDistance();
    // Prints the distance value to the serial monitor
    Serial.print("Distance: ");
    Serial.println(distance);

    delay(500);
}

void getDistance()
{
    // Clear trigPin
    digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(2);

    // trigPin HIGH por 10ms
    digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(10);
    digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);

    //Reads echoPin, returns the travel time of the sound wave in ms
    duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);

    // Calculating the distance, in centimeters, using the formula described in the first section.
    distance = duration * 0.034 / 2;

    // Sends the distance value to Firebase
    Firebase.setFloat("distance", distance);

}
```

I am a computer graduate so i do not have much knowledge about nodemcu. I saw some documentations about nodemcu. I want to show the data obtained by the ultrasonic distance sensor in the realtime database of firebase. But i am not able to figure out why i am not able to get output of **serial.println(distance)** in the com5 window even though the code compiles successfully .
This is what i get when running the program

```
Executable segment sizes:


IROM   : 330560          - code in flash         (default or ICACHE_FLASH_ATTR) 


IRAM   : 27760   / 32768 - code in IRAM          (ICACHE_RAM_ATTR, ISRs...) 


DATA   : 1408  )         - initialized variables (global, static) in RAM/HEAP 


RODATA : 2044  ) / 81920 - constants             (global, static) in RAM/HEAP 


BSS    : 25160 )         - zeroed variables      (global, static) in RAM/HEAP 


Sketch uses 361772 bytes (34%) of program storage space. Maximum is 1044464 bytes.
Global variables use 28612 bytes (34%) of dynamic memory, leaving 53308 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 81920 bytes.
esptool.py v2.8
Serial port COM5
Connecting....
Chip is ESP8266EX
Features: WiFi
Crystal is 26MHz
MAC: ec:fa:bc:c1:44:d2
Uploading stub...
Running stub...
Stub running...
Configuring flash size...
Auto-detected Flash size: 4MB
Compressed 365920 bytes to 264395...

Writing at 0x00000000... (5 %)
Writing at 0x00004000... (11 %)
Writing at 0x00008000... (17 %)
Writing at 0x0000c000... (23 %)
Writing at 0x00010000... (29 %)
Writing at 0x00014000... (35 %)
Writing at 0x00018000... (41 %)
Writing at 0x0001c000... (47 %)
Writing at 0x00020000... (52 %)
Writing at 0x00024000... (58 %)
Writing at 0x00028000... (64 %)
Writing at 0x0002c000... (70 %)
Writing at 0x00030000... (76 %)
Writing at 0x00034000... (82 %)
Writing at 0x00038000... (88 %)
Writing at 0x0003c000... (94 %)
Writing at 0x00040000... (100 %)
Wrote 365920 bytes (264395 compressed) at 0x00000000 in 23.4 seconds (effective 125.3 kbit/s)...
Hash of data verified.

Leaving...
Hard resetting via RTS pin...
```

[image: Here is the serial window after executing]

Is the ultrasonic sensor not getting enough power supply as nodemcu is connected to my laptop?
Please help me out and let me know if more information is required.

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/402066/esp8266-free-gpios-for-relay-switching/404845#404845

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `echoPin` Is defined as `3`. GPIO3 of the NodeMCU is also the “RX” pin needed for serial communication to the host. This might explain why you don’t see any output. You should change it to a different pin (for example pin 5 / D1 is a safe choice).

Each pin on the NodeMCU has a “GPIO” number (which is just the pin number as defined by the ESP8266 architecture) and a corresponding “Dx” designation (which is usually marked on the NodeMCU board).

Which GPIO pin corresponds to which which “D” pin is shown in pinout diagrams, like the one [here](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp8266-pinout-reference-gpios/). Scroll to the NodeMCU 12-E pinout.

Some of the safest pins to use are:

- Pin 5 (D1)
- Pin 4 (D2)
- Pin 12 (D6)
- Pin 13 (D7)
- Pin 14 (D5)

Some of the other pins could also be used, but have some restrictions, as you can see on the page I linked to.

Note that pins 12-14 are used for SPI and pins 4 and 5 are (normally) used for (software) I2C. If you want to control hardware that uses these protocols, these are the default pins it uses.